# Matrix fractional function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We know that the following function is convex $$f(\mathbf{x,Y})=\mathbf{x^TY^{-1}x}$$ where $\mathbf{Y}$ is a positive definite matrix of size $n$ and $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector of size $n$. How to use this result and formally prove that $$g(\mathbf{w})=\mathbf{b^TWA(A^TWA)^{-1}A^TWb}$$ is convex where $\mathbf{w}$ is a column vector of size $n$ and $\mathbf{b}$ is a column vector of size $n$, $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix of size $n\times m$ and $\mathbf{W}=diag(\mathbf{w})$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convexity is closed under linear transformations, and you have $f(A^TWb, A^TWA)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: We know that if $f(\mathbf{x})$ is convex then $g(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{Sx+d})$ is also convex. So in my question what should be the value of $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{d}$?

Comment: I wrote the transformation for you. If you want to do the gritty details, you will first have to write the pair $(x,W)$ as one vector by vectorizing $W$ and concatenating the variables, and then you would have to write the transformation $A^TWA$ in that variable, and thus write the product using some Kronecker trick $vec(A^TWA) = (?) vec(W)$ etc.Boring book-keeping no added value in terms of theory.

Comment: I was also thinking the same. I got the idea. Thank you for your comment and answer.